# Uploading an image on server

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want that whenever add button is clicked then default.jpg (located at dekstop) should be uploaded on server.

For this I have tried following code :-

Code of jsp page :-

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="AddProductServlet">
Id<input type="text" name="id"><br><br>
Name<input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="imagename" style="visibility: hidden;"> 
<input type="submit" value="Add"></form>
```

Code of AddProductServlet :-

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String value="";

    String itemName = "";
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

    if (!isMultipart)
    {  }
    else
    {
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List items = null;

    try
    {
        items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    }
    catch(FileUploadException e){}

    Iterator itr = items.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext())
    {
        FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();

        if (item.isFormField())
        {
            if(item.getFieldName().equals("imagename"))
            {
                try{
                File savedFile = 
                        new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"productimages\\default.jpg");
                item.write(savedFile);}
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.print("Image can't be added.Error occurred in uploading image to server."+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            else{
            String name = item.getFieldName();
            value = item.getString();
            }

        }
        }}}
```

Now the problem is that a file named default.jpg is getting uploaded to server but it doesn't have any content.

Can anyone solve my problem?

Comment: How do you upload an image file? You don't have an HTML component, `<input type="file" name="xxx"...>`.

Comment: Here I don't want to show Browse option..I want that default.jpg should be uploaded to server every time when this file is run.

Comment: By using the above code the file is being uploaded but it doesn't have any content on server probably because while uploading its location is not specified.Is there any way to specify the location of image (from where it should be picked for uploading) ?

Comment: How can you assume that a file can be uploaded to a **remote server** by simply putting its path into a text field as can be seen in your example? You have to upload the file object anyhow.

Comment: I want to ask how will the default.jpg located on my dekstop will be uploaded ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `<input type="file">`. If you don't want the user to choose an image, the element should be hidden and it's value assigned by your code.

See a good tutorial on the subject here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm

Comment: But here I don't want to show a choose image option.I want that default.jpg should be uploaded to server when this file is run.

Comment: @user3542411, You can't do that. Would you want any old website to be able to choose to force you to upload any of your files they wanted without your consent?  That's why its not possible.

Comment: "If you don't want the user to choose an image, the element should be hidden and it's value assigned by your code." On what browser does that work? I want to make sure to NOT use that one!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.coderanch.com/t/117336/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/Hidden-input-type-file-technique